# petición AJAX error 500

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Tengo el siguiente código

```
function invitarEmpleado(e){

if (e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('plan')){

    const idInvitado = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');

    console.log(idInvitado);
    console.log(QueryString.id);

    const respuesta = confirm('Estás segur@?');

    if(respuesta){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Abrir la conexión
    xhr.open('GET', `../controller/empleado_reunion_controlador.php?idEmpleado_fk=${idInvitado}&idReunion_fk=${QueryString.id}&accion=invitar`, true);

    //Pasar los datos
    xhr.onload = function(){
       if (this.status === 200) {
        const resultado = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if(resultado.respuesta == 'correcto') {
            mostrarNotificacion('Empleado invitado', 'correcto')
        }else{
            mostrarNotificacion('Hubo un error', 'error');
        }
        }
    }

    xhr.send();

}
```

}

}

Esto va al siguiente controlador donde recojo las variables y las guardo para hacer lo que corresponda:

```
if($_GET['accion'] == 'invitar'){

$idReunion_fk = $_GET['idReunion_fk'];

$idEmpleado_fk = $_GET['idEmpleado_fk'];

}
```

todo va bien, cuando click en el elemento que quiero, la consola me muestra los parámetros que recojo, sin embargo, justo después imprime el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La linea 43, la del error, es la línea en la que tengo el xhr.send(), o sea, el final de la función.

Esto es lo que me devuelve el network del inspector:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda por favor!!

Comment: Revisa en la parte de "Network" del inspector de elementos. El problema está en el archivo PHP que no has puesto completo, edita la pregunta, agrega dicha información y también los detalles del contenido de la pestaña network. Saludos :D Por cierto, mira las N preguntas que existen con la misma temática: AJAX PHP error 500, prácticamente todas tienen el mismo proceso de debugging.

Comment: Me parece que al final te sobra un cierre de llave.

Comment: Ya está editada la respuesta e incluido el network @fredyfx

Comment: gracias @cooper. Las llaves están bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, gracias a @fredyfx por aconsejarme que buscara la pregunta. No sabía como hacerlo puesto que pensé que este tipo de petición, aunque sea asíncrona, no es AJAX en sí porque además no estoy usando jQuery.

El error estaba en el controlador php. Al hacer la inserción de los parámetros que recibo, estaba poniendo mal uno de los valores. Nada que ver con  el código de la petición.

```
    if($_GET['accion'] == 'invitar'){

$idReunion_fk = $_GET['idReunion_fk'];

$idEmpleado_fk = $_GET['idEmpleado_fk'];

$nexo = new Empleado_reunion();

$nexo->setIdReunion_fk($idReunion_fk);
$nexo->setIdEmpleado_fk($idEmpleado_fk);
$nexo->setConfirmacion(0);

$reunionDao = new Empleado_reunion_DAO();

$reunionDao->insertarNexo($nexo);

}
```

en el setConfirmación() estaba metiendo el parámetro false (setConfirmacion(false)). En la base de datos, los valores booleanos se interpretan como enteros, por lo que esa funcion solo puede recibir como parámetros 0 (false) y 1 (true). Por eso no funcionaba.

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Con cariño el consejo hermano, siempre se encuentra ayuda por estos lares, ¿ves que faltaba que coloques el PHP en la pregunta? En fin, me alegra que hayas solucionado el problema, sigue desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: Recuerda marcar el check verde para aceptar la respuesta, ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio :D